# What level of fluency should one have when discussing Islam in a second language?

Tags: language

When talking about Allah, the Qur'an, or anything in Islam really, we should be knowledgeable:

> ...My Lord has only forbidden...  ...that you say about Allah that which you do not know. -- [Qur'an 7:33](http://quran.com/7:33)

As I live in a country (China) where the local language is not my native language, I'm consequently hesitant to speak about Islam in Chinese in case I inadvertently misspeak.

**Question**: What level of fluency should one have when discussing Islam in a second language?

While I understand that I can reasonably expect to be forgiven for isolated mistakes, I nevertheless shouldn't say things about Allah, the Qur'an, etc., recklessly.

Comment: you can just give them a entrance about Islam , such about our main believes then if they ask more give them a physical copy of Quran or such things !

Comment: This seems to me opinion based I've heard many people (among them scholars) using the expression "Convey (my teachings) to the people even if it were a single sentence... (http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/128) " as a general invitation to do d'awa, but it seems to be contrdictory  to your quoted verse!

Comment: Today I called the Qur'an "Islam's most important tree" (in Chinese, book is "shu" first tone, while I said "shu" fourth tone). I'm not sure if I should laugh or pray for forgiveness.

Comment: Praying for forgiveness is never wrong read https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/99 or https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/4